# Length of dataframe inside UDF function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write a complex **User Defined Function (UDF)** that takes multiple columns as input. Something like:

```
val uudf = udf{(val:Int, lag:Int, cumsum_p:Double) => val + lag + cum_p} // actually a more complex function but let's make it simple
```

The third parameter cumsum_p indicate is a cumulative sum of p where p is a the length of the **group** it is computed. Because this udf will then be used in a groupby.

**I come up with this solution** which is almost ok:

```
val uudf = udf{(val:Int, lag:Int, cumsum_p:Double) => val + lag + cum_p}
val w = Window.orderBy($"sale_qty")
df.withColumn("needThat", 
    uudf(col("sale_qty"),
       lead("sale_qty",1).over(w), sum(lit(1/length_group)).over(w)
    )
).show()
```

**The problem is** that if I replace `lit(1/length_group)` with `lit(1/count("sale_qty"))` the created column now contains only 1 element which lead to an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute `count("sale_qty")` first:

```
val w = Window.orderBy($"sale_qty")
df
.withColumn("cnt",count($"sale_qty").over()) 
.withColumn("needThat", 
    uudf(col("sale_qty"),
       lead("sale_qty",1).over(w), sum(lit(1)/$"cnt").over(w)
    )
).show()
```